# Meschat is displaying blank page in Firefox

Tags: firefox, webgl, drake

The other day I noticed that Meshcat was no longer displaying in Firefox on Ubuntu 20.04. The server would load, but just display a blank white page. My recent Firefox version is 100.0.2, and it was working fine last week (before the update). Upon inspection, this is the traceback that appears in the console:

```
THREE.WebGLRenderer: Error creating WebGL context.
Failed to create WebGL context: WebGL creation failed: 
* tryNativeGL ()
* Exhausted GL driver options. (FEATURE_FAILURE_WEBGL_EXHAUSTED_DRIVERS)
```

I have tried changing **webgl.force-enabled=true** in about:config, but that did not work. I am tagging as drake in case any other firefox users have experienced the same. My only fix for now is switching to Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 100.0.2 on Ubuntu 20.04 with Meshcat git sha 65781fc has been working fine for me.

Have you tried rebooting?  Sometimes Ubuntu's automatic upgrades cause OpenGL contexts to stop working until after a reboot.

Comment: Rebooting did not help, but I could make sure that I'm using the same Meshcat version